# Why is Postgres not starting?

Tags: linux, postgresql

Somehow my Postgres is not anymore starting:

```
# psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

```
# ./postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 8.4 database server                                                                        * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2013-03-05 12:03:16 CET LOG:  could not create IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
2013-03-05 12:03:16 CET LOG:  invalid authentication method "peer"
2013-03-05 12:03:16 CET CONTEXT:  line 84 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/pg_hba.conf"
2013-03-05 12:03:16 CET LOG:  end-of-line before authentication method
2013-03-05 12:03:16 CET CONTEXT:  line 89 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/pg_hba.conf"
2013-03-05 12:03:16 CET FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
                                                                                                          [fail]
```

Comment: Your pg_hba.conf file has errors. You're also trying to bind to an IPV6 socket, but don't have IPV6 enabled on your server (possibly).

Comment: hmm.. the config was working previously... and as far as I know, nothing has changed in that area... any basic checks that I could do? for the peer auth or IPv6 ?

Comment: Well, the file may have been corrupted? Check the lines they indicate, make sure they are correctly configured.

Comment: hmm.. ok, thanks, I got the server up running by changing "peer" to "trust" ... that's a bit of a monkey patch, but in this experimental setup it doesn't matter.. more reading to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `peer` authentication method appeared in PostgreSQL 9.1 and you're using 8.4. This is the reason for `invalid authentication method "peer"`.
See the docs at [Client authentication (8.4)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/client-authentication.html) and  [Client authentication (9.1)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/client-authentication.html).

The paths look like it's a Debian or Ubuntu OS. It's not likely that the change happened automatically, because if PG 9.1 was installed side-by-side on the system with Debian packages, it would have created a new `pg_hba.conf` inside `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main` and not overwritten anything from 8.4.

Comment: ok, I see.. somehow, I installed a Postgres instance via a Chef recipe, and probably, there went something wrong in a provision run... thanks, for the input above.